# What is the best way to compare two NSArrays and detect changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

My requirement is to determine changes in address book (which contact(s) and which fields(s) has been changed since the application was last opened.

Now I have two NSArrays as arrSavedContacts(contains previous address book contacts) and arrContacts(current address book contacts). This is how the two arrays looks like

**arrSavedContacts**

```
{
    firstName = Gayan;
    id = 224;
    lastName = Udaha;
    phones =         (
                    {
            label = Mobile;
            value = "123456789";
        }
    );
},
    {
    firstName = Chandrananda;
    id = 225;
    lastName = "";
    phones =         (
                    {
            label = Mobile;
            value = "234567891";
        }
    );
},
    {
    firstName = Joe;
    id = 228;
    lastName = B8;
    phones =         (
                    {
            label = Mobile;
            value = "345678912";
        }
    );
},
```

**arrContacts**

```
{
    firstName = FirstName Changed;
    id = 224;
    lastName = Udaha;
    phones =         (
                    {
            label = Mobile;
            value = "123456789";
        }
    );
},
    {
    firstName = Chandrananda;
    id = 225;
    lastName = "";
    phones =         (
                    {
            label = Mobile;
            value = "345678912";
        }
    );
},
```

As the above two arrays, we can notice two changes, 3rd item is deleted and the firstName get changed in the 1st item.

Since we can have thousands of items in the address book, my question is, what is the best and optimum way to compare those two arrays and detect the changed items (deleted, added, changes for the internal fields)?

A code example is highly appreciated

Comment: Your data structure makes it nearly impossible to do what you want. You really need a dictionary of dictionary instead of an array of dictionary. The outer dictionary should be keyed on some sort of unique id for each contact entry. Then you can correlate the two (saved and changed) dictionaries by the keys. Then you can compare each corresponding inner dictionary looking for changes.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the idea, highly appreciated if you can show some example

Comment: Start with `arrSavedContacts`. You have an array of dictionary. Instead, put all of the dictionaries in a dictionary instead of an array. Your existing dictionaries will be the values in the dictionary and some sort of unique id for each contact will be its key. Now do the same for `arrContacts`. Now the each contact will have the same unique id in the two sets of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to check the changes, add and delete. Please check it, If you don't understand please comment...

```
NSMutableArray *oldArr =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Gayan",
                                                             @"id" : @224,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"Udaha",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"123456789"
                                                                      }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
                                                         @{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Chandrananda",
                                                             @"id" : @225,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"234567891"
                                                                         }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
                                                         @{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Joe",
                                                             @"id" : @226,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"345678912"
                                                                         }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
]];

NSMutableArray *newArr =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Gayan",
                                                             @"id" : @224,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"Udaha",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"123456789"
                                                                         }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
                                                         @{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Chandrananda",
                                                             @"id" : @225,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"11111111"
                                                                         }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
                                                         @{
                                                             @"firstName" : @"Luan",
                                                             @"id" : @229,
                                                             @"lastName" : @"",
                                                             @"phones": @[
                                                                     @{
                                                                         @"label" : @"Mobile",
                                                                         @"value" : @"55555555"
                                                                         }
                                                                     ]
                                                             },
                                                         ]];


NSMutableSet *oldSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:oldArr];
NSMutableSet *newSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:newArr];

//1: Get filter all changed, add, delete items

[oldSet minusSet:newSet];
[newSet minusSet:oldSet];

NSArray *remainOldArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[oldSet allObjects]];
NSArray *remainNewArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[newSet allObjects]];

if (remainNewArr.count == 0 && remainOldArr.count == 0) {
    // there is no changes.
    return ;
}

//2: detect which items changed,add,delete

NSMutableArray *arrayChangedItems = nil;
NSMutableArray *arrayDeleteItems = nil;
NSMutableArray *arrayAddItems =nil;

NSPredicate *pre1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.id IN %@",[remainOldArr valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];
NSPredicate *pre2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT self.id IN %@",[remainOldArr valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];
NSPredicate *pre3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT self.id IN %@",[remainNewArr valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];

arrayChangedItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[remainNewArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre1]];
arrayAddItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[remainNewArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre2]];
arrayDeleteItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[remainOldArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre3]];
```

Comment: I tested the code, but every time it returns empty arrays for arrayAddItems and arrayDeleteItems. arrayChangedItems is always the full set of items

Comment: super cool answer. How ever in my case it needs to change the predicates slightly like this. pre2 and pre3 should use arrays before get the minus set operation. Also, the same arrays should use to filteredArrayUsingPredicate operation

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to what **rmaddy** suggested, it makes sense to have data in dictionary of dictionary to easily find out deletions at first place based on unique IDs. For instance this is how your base dictionary should look like:

```
{ 224 = {
        firstName = Gayan;
        id = 224;
        lastName = Udaha;
        phones = (
               {
                 label = Mobile;
                 value = "123456789";
               }
                );
        }

    225 = {
        firstName = Chandrananda;
        id = 225;
        lastName = "";
        phones =  (
               {
                 label = Mobile;
                 value = "234567891";
                }
                 );
    }
}
```

Now, once your data is set correctly, you can add a category on `NSDictionary`and implement following method:

```
- (NSArray*)changedKeysIn:(NSDictionary*)iAnotherDict {
    NSMutableArray *changedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id key in self) {
        if(![[self objectForKey:key] isEqual:[iAnotherDict objectForKey:key]])
            [changedKeys addObject:key];
        }

        return changedKeys;
}
```

Then simply call it like:

```
[baseDict changedKeysIn:anotherDict];
```

Comment: This is a start. This only works for keys found in both dictionaries. Logic needs to be added keys added or removed from one or the other dictionary. And logic needs to be added to see what changed in a changed contact dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I managed to get the data sets as dictionaries, with a uniq key for each inner dictionary. 224 =     {
        firstName = Gayan;
        lastName = Udaha;
        phones =         (
                        {
                label = Mobile;
                value = "1234567890";
            }
        );
    };   But still unable to figure out the logic for detecting inner field changes

Comment: @sajaz Once you know a two corresponding dictionaries are different, you will have to compare each field one at a time. There's no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

How about…

```
// put new contacts in a dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[arrContacts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id theNewContact, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    [aDictionary setObject:theNewContact forKey:[theNewContact valueForKey:@"id"]];
}];

// check each old contact
[arrSavedContacts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id theOldContact, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSDictionary *aNewContact = [aDictionary objectForKey:[theOldContact valueForKey:@"id"]];
    if (aNewContact == nil)
    {
        // delete old contact
    }
    else
    {
        if (![aNewContact isEqual:theOldContact])
        {
            // update old contact
        }
        // remove existing contact from the dictionary
        [aDictionary removeObjectForKey:[theOldContact valueForKey:@"id"]];
    }
}];

// new contacts
[aDictionary allValues];
```

Each array is enumerated once.